# Run-Time error '9' using nested For loops in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to loop through two lists, of which there are rows that have the same data (person's name) in the first column. For matching names, I'd like to copy the data from the second data set (x) in cell (H,x) to the first dataset's(y) cell (H,y). In my attempt, I have used the following code. For simplicity's sake, I just stuck the second dataset under the first (starting at row 216), although I suppose it'd be cleaner to put it in a different worksheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim counter As Integer
Dim bigCounter As Integer


For counter = 2 To 214
    For bigCounter = 216 To 428
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(A, counter).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(A, bigCounter) Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(H, counter).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(H, bigCounter)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next bigCounter
Next counter

End Sub
```

I don't understand why I'm getting a run time error 9 as I can't tell when I'm trying to access data outside what's available, and that is my understanding of the error.

Comment: Something that immediately jumps out is your column index references should be in quotations.  For example, `.Cells(A, counter)` should be `.Cells("A", counter)`.  I also believe they are backwards.  The correct syntax is `.Cells([Row Index],[Column Index])`

Comment: Wait, really? Why is it row, column in VBA when most other places in excel use a column, row notation? For example, the top left corner shows "C6" when I click cell at column C row 6, formatting rules uses Column, row, etc...

Comment: Turns out I misunderstood the naming structure, among other things. I didn't realize that the "sheetname" format refers to the custom name I set, rather than the permanent name like Sheet1, Sheet2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed two things that may be contributing to your error.

First, column indexes should be in quotations.

So `.Cells(A, counter)` should be `.Cells("A", counter)`

But even then that's not quite right because `.Cells` expects the row index first followed by the column index, and what you're saying here is *go to row A* which doesn't make sense (it is expecting a number, not a letter).

Changing these two issues results in the following code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim counter As Integer
Dim bigCounter As Integer


For counter = 2 To 214
    For bigCounter = 216 To 428
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, "A").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(bigCounter, "A").Value Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, "H").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(bigCounter, "H")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next bigCounter
Next counter



End Sub
```

This runs fine on my machine now, no more run-time errors, but I am not sure if it produces the results you are after.

Comment: Why does VBA use rows, columns when elsewhere in excel a columns, rows format is used? For example, conditional formatting, etc?

Comment: Also, I have implemented your code verbatim, but am still getting the error. The debugger halts at the If statement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you might be referencing cells on a spreadsheet that do not exist, but it depends on what version of Excel you are using. There are a maximum of 256 columns total in all Excel worksheets before the 2010 version. Regardless, and given your comments above, it would appear you have the row and column parameters backward. It is Cells([row], [column]) NOT Cells([column], [row]). You seemed to have indicated when you said "starting at row 216..." that bigCounter iterates over the rows and not the columns.

Comment: In Excel 2010 and later there are 16,384 columns.

Comment: @ChipsLetten Oh yeah... forgot about that . Thanks for pointing it out. I edited my answer for accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

The `Cells` method usually takes the row first and then the column. The column letter should also be in speech marks.

When you are comparing the value in cells, you should explicitly use the `.Value` property.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim counter As Integer
Dim bigCounter As Integer

For counter = 2 To 214
    For bigCounter = 216 To 428
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, "A").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(bigCounter, "A").Value Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, "H").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(bigCounter, "H").Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next bigCounter
Next counter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure "Sheet1" is there in your Worksheet
2. like Joshua said `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(A, counter)` is incorrect I think it shout be `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 1)` for Row "A"